# next js with ssr enabled: Og image not displaying while sharing using linkedln

Tags: image, amazon-s3, next.js

I am forming og image(s3 link) based on id send as query params.

In app.js, inside head, I am assigning og:image content value to s3 link based on router path.

```
const { query } = useRouter();
const { id } = query;
<Head>
 {router.pathname === "/certificate/course-complete" &&
          <meta
            property="og:image"
            content={`${process.env.CERTIFICATE_S3_ORIGIN}/course-complete/${id}.jpg`}
          />
 }
</Head>
```

Now, when i inspect the page, i look for og:image meta, its present and its valus is s3 url. But, its not read by https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/ or https://socialsharepreview.com/. they are not getting those og:image from the url.

If i hard code the s3 link, then linkedln inspector is getting the og:image and its working fine.

```
<Head>
 <meta
            property="og:image"
            content={`${process.env.CERTIFICATE_S3_ORIGIN}/course-complete/199111.jpg`}
          />
</Head>
```

Please help how can i generate dynamic og:image(s3 link formed using id as query params from the url) for a page in next js

getInitialProps used in _document.js

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
```

in netlify, the following is used to run the application.
next build and next export

code to set meta tags

```
import { Col, Row } from 'antd';
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { id } = context.query;
  return {
    props: {id: id}
  }
}

const Certificate = (props) => {

  return (
      <>
       <NextSeo
        canonical={`${process.env.CERTIFICATE_URL}/?id=${props.id}`}
        openGraph={{
          url: `${process.env.CERTIFICATE_S3_ORIGIN}/`,
          images: [
            {
              url: `${process.env.CERTIFICATE_S3_ORIGIN}/${props.id}.jpg`,
              width: 800,
              height: 600,
              type: 'image/jpeg',
            }
          ],
        }}
      />
    // code here
      </>
  );
};


export default Certificate;
```

Comment: did you see this package ? https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo

Comment: The issue is most likely related to the fact that you're only rendering the `og:image`'s `<meta>` tag on the client-side. If you look at the page source (not `Inspect`, but actually `View Page Source`), do you see the meta tag there? Can you post the full code for the component where you're adding the meta tag?

Comment: @H9ee, i had used this lib too but same issue.

Comment: @juliomalves, i am adding other tags also like  url, canonical, title, description etc but for keeping code concise, i had added og:image in asked question.

Comment: @juliomalves

upon checking the meta in source page, the id of s3 link formed from url(https://example.com/?id=006155) is undefined. 


meta property="og:image" content="https://<s3_url>/course-complete/undefined.jpg"/>

Comment: Is that specific page using `getServerSideProps`? If it doesn't then the `id` you pass in the query param will only be available on the client-side. The page needs to be fully SSRd for the query params to be available on the server.

Comment: @juliomalves. Thanks! Now, the current next js project uses getInitialProps. If I use getServerSideProps in local, i can see the og:image displaying but the application is hosted on netlify. Using getInitialProps and getServerSideProps is bit difficult. Can you suggest how can i use getInitialProps, getServerSideProps and npm export in netlify.

Comment: `getServerSideProps` can't be used with `next export`, see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features. If you're using `next export` you're not using SSR, your pages are statically generated.

Comment: Can you share the code you have in `getInitialProps` as well as the full code for the component where you're setting the `og:image` meta tag?

Comment: @juliomalves

I have updated the question with code. 

Yes, I got this that getServerSideProps can't be used with next export

and also, to use server side rendering, i need to modify next.config.js to include serverless target where i am using exportPathMap and other code and it does not make sense to remove all code in next.config.js to include target as serverless just for sharing feature.

Comment: @juliomalves

when i use the next build && next start, the production build in netlify fails. 

here is the message at the end of deployment.
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

and the error message is  Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime

am i missing something? i was using next export previously and it was working fine absolutely. 

I referred the flow from here. 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/gssp-export